# Handling parents events from child component, in a props down events up approach

Tags: encapsulation, user-interface, event-handling, component-design, reusability

<s>This question is language/framework agnostic.</s> **EDIT:** *The comments and answers have highlighted how different languages approach events differently, which made me realize this question isn't really neutral across languages or frameworks. To clarify, I'm using Vanilla JS, and my components are built with [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components). While I do need a JS-focused solution, I'm also keen on understanding the bigger picture, as if JavaScript wasn't a limiting factor.*

I'm working on a canvas component (**EDIT:** *i.e. a web component encapsulating a `canvas` element*) that allows users to draw a rectangle. For data flow, I use the *props-down, events-up* principle: parents pass data to children using the children's properties, and children pass data to parents by raising events.

An issue arises when the user intends to create a rectangle that touches the canvas' edges: they must left-click with pixel-perfect precision on the edge, which can be challenging. To enhance usability, I want to enable users to start drawing from outside the component.

---

**EDIT:** *To clarify, as long as the mouse is down, the rectangle should be updated based on the mouse's position. The user should be allowed to move the mouse freely, without the rectangle "freezing" when the mouse leaves the child component. The component should behave as if it were a "window" through which the user can see the rectangle, which is drawn behind it.*

*Here is an updated illustration:*

[image: Illustration]

---

Since the component is only aware of mouse events occurring within its boundaries, we cannot naively react to these events from within the component. The obvious solution would be to handle them from the parent:

```
// Pseudo-code
Parent {
    onMouseDown() {
        dragging = true
        startPosition = ...
    }
    onMouseMove() {
        if(dragging)
            child.rectangle = [startPosition, currentPosition]
    }
    onMouseUp() {
        dragging = false
    }
}
```

However, this approach somewhat violates the component encapsulation: as drawing the rectangle is a behavior inherently associated with the component, it should really be encapsulated within it. Furthermore, this approach hurts reusability, necessitating each parent to individually handle the mouse events when reusing the component in different contexts.

A different approach is to pass the child a reference to the parent, so it can handle the mouse events for itself:

```
Parent {
    initialize() {
        child.parent = this
    }
}
Child {
    parent.onMouseDown() {
        dragging = true
        startPosition = ...
    }
    parent.onMouseMove() {
        if(dragging)
            DrawRectangle(...)
    }
    onMouseUp() {
        dragging = false
    }
}
```

But should the child really have access, let alone control, over the parent state? I think not.

What is the proper way of handling this behavior?

Comment: Dear downvoter. Voting down with no feedback whatsoever is counterproductive.

Comment: "Dragging" the mouse versus "moving" is a matter of state: is the primary mouse button already down upon entering the bounds of the child component? If so, then start drawing a rectangle. This is where a language agnostic question doesn't fit, because JavaScript has a [mouseenter event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) (and `mouseleave`), during which your child should interrogate the state of the mouse to see if the primary button is already pressed. It's not clear if you can do this, though.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Let’s say the dragging starts from within the boundaries, and finishes outside. The rect should not disappear but “follow” the mouse. This is why I believe `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are not suitable. I do implement it in JS, and essentially my question is whether or not the component should access `document` events.

Comment: Again, upon leaving the bounds of the child component, if the primary mouse button is still pressed, keep the rectangle. I'm on the cusp of writing an answer. This is an interesting question. Basically, something higher than the parent and child components needs to inform elements of these events. Think of how events are implemented in browsers. Something else is responsible for propagating these events amongst the tree structure of components (or DOM nodes, if you will).

Comment: @GregBurghardt interesting approach! Would be glad to read your answer. However, please keep in mind that if the mouse is still down when leaving the boundaries, I don׳t want the rectangle to freeze, but to keep changing based on the mouse position. Tommorow I will try to add a jsfiddle/animation to improve the clarity of the question.

Comment: What happens when the mouse leaves the parent boundaries before mouseup? Maybe dragging should be stored in a mouse object.

Comment: @GregBurghardt
Please review the question. I have edited it to address your comments.

Comment: @candied_orange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given 100% flexibility in the language/framework used, "best practice" would suggest that you pass in a mouse interface to the constructor of the component. ie

```
RectComponent
{
   IMouse mouse
   RectComponent(IMouse mouse) {
     this.mouse = mouse;
     this.mouse.OnClick += dowhatever //remember to unsubscribe!
     ...
   }
}
```

Similar to your passing in the parent component.

However, There are some issues with the event subscription and it looks like you are working in a web browser so you have a bunch of constraints that might make this a bit ugly to implement.

Instead you could do the binding of event at the top level of your page.

```
Parent
{
   RectComponent child
   
   onMouseDown => { child.MouseDown(mouse.x, mouse.y); }
   ...
}
```

With the binding done at the top level, you can orchestrate the events easily over multiple child components, but also keep the logic of what those components actually do when the events happen in the components themselves.

Personally I would be tempted to go further and have:

```
Parent
{
   RectComponent child
   
   onMouseDown => { child.StartRectangle(mouse.x, mouse.y); }
   ...
}
```

This brings some of the "logic" out into your parent, but its fair enough, just say the component doesn't care how you draw, it could be a mouse or keyboard or programmed event and its no longer the responsibility of the component.

This makes for a neater more flexible components with a single place of event orchestration at the top level parent.

You could also go with a mediator pattern, but I think this is basically the same as passing in the parent, but with more code.

Comment: Thank you. Please note I updated the question with more details. I like your first approach, but as I use JS, it is a bit challenging: There is no `mouse` object of some sort,  and therefore I cannot pass it as an argument. However, what if instead of using the `document` object to access mouse events, I simply use `window`? `window` is just the execution context, and not part of the DOM, which means that the component will not actually have a reference to an ancestor.

Comment: I would still recommend my approach of putting the binding in at the top level and calling child.startRectange(). you will presumably need to know lots of stuff about the child's position relative to the mouse and pick up on mouse clicks that don't intersect etc

Comment: The only thing that bothers me with this approach is that every parent would need to rewrite the same orchestration logic. What do you think about extracting it into a separate class, so every parent who has this canvas component as a child could use it?

Comment: I would advise against that unless you can completely compartmentalise the logic. In which case you might as well just use window.mouse in your component. For example. What if you have multiple children on the same page, but want the rectangle to only be drawn in the selected one? By having the binding done in the parent, this is possible. if you abstract it out to the child or a 3rd object then its hard or impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the level of abstraction you want to have. If you limit the implementation to a single element then yes, you inevitably leak implementation details in the first approach.
However, the second approach is even worse in my opinion cause it negates reusability, since the user will have to wire it all up every single time.

How about instead of limiting yourself to a single element, you treat it as a black box which includes all the elements, mechanics and wiring to just work? Essentially, what everyone calls nowadays a component is the ideal abstraction level.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, and give me some concrete examples? Please note I updated the question.